# Calling a function in a form

Tags: c#, forms

please be gentle. I'm very new to coding and finding my way as I go along.

I have created a set of client / server sockets in a class called communications which are all functioning OK.

How do I use the trigger of receiving a set of data to call a set of functions within a form to update the contents of the form?

thanks

Comment: Being as gentle as I can; you need to show us some code. This is far to broad to answer without seeing what you're trying to do

Comment: @Jamiec I thinks he is looking for an idea and not implementation

Comment: As @Ali suggests, i was looking for guidance what to learn

Answer (score 2):

One option is an `event`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/

If your communication class receives something to trigger it can publish that to the event. Anything that has subscribed to that event will receive the information you've specified.

Be sure to clean up subscriptions before you dispose of any subscribers.

Note that depending on your approach you're probably already using events since you're using forms. Things like `myButton.Click += ....`

Comment: Thank you, I think that gives me a clue.
Watching youtube now to understand and learn to incorporate events.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a reference of your form (or view) to the communications class. and call the method that responsible of changing the content of your form

```
class Communications { 

     private MyForm myForm;
     ....
}
```

---

```
 ...
 //the code when you receiving a set of data
 this.myForm.ChangeContent(data);
 ...
```

but you need to be aware that when receiving data on other thread than MainThread(UIThread) then you figure out how to change UI from other thread (I think you can find answers here in Stackoverflow)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I would guess that it's because it promotes an extremely strong coupling between the class and the form.

Comment: @McAden  more clean solution will require more details that could be not related to the question, beside that  I don't think a solution with bad design should be downvoted